# Swift implement setter without getter

Tags: swift, setter, getter

How do you implement setter without getter in Swift? I need to call a method when the value is set:

```
var selectedIndex : Int{
    set {
        selectItemAtIndex(newValue)
    }
}
```

but in Swift, you are required to use both getter and setter, not just one.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to non-readable property. just use method `SetSelectedIndex(Int)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the property observer `didSet`. This will be called immediately after setting the value.

```
var selectedIndex: Int {
  didSet {
    selectItemAtIndex(selectedIndex)
  }
}
```